# Does Spring Boot ApplicationReadyEvent happen before or after properties are being set to the environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm having trouble performing some logic based on a property im trying to get on application startup.

I have created a listener:

```
class MyApplicationListener : ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
  companion object : KLogging()

  override fun onApplicationEvent(event: ApplicationReadyEvent) {
    event.applicationContext.environment.getProperty("my.property")?.run {
      try {
        logger.info { "my.property exists!" }
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        closeApplication(e, event.applicationContext)
      }
    } ?: closeApplication(RuntimeException(), event.applicationContext)
  }

  private fun closeApplication(e: Exception, context: ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
    logger.error(e) { e.message }
    context.close()
  }
```

I'm having an application-my-test.yml properties file containing the following:

```
my:
  property: test
```

When I'm trying to test this functionality via a JUnit test:

```
class MyTest {

  @Test
  fun `test my.property exist or fail`() {
    assertThrows<RuntimeException> {
      SpringApplication.run(MyApplication::class.java, "--spring.profiles.active=my-test")
    }
  }
}
```

I always get to the closeApplication function since my.property is null.

the thing is that when I'm passing "my.property" as an argument it works.:

```
class MyTest {

  @Test
  fun `test my.property exist or fail`() {
    assertThrows<RuntimeException> {
      SpringApplication.run(MyApplication::class.java, "--my.property=test")
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the difference, and why it does't work in the first use-case, any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, where did you keep YML file ?

Comment: src/test/resources

Comment: Tried with Java, it works. When properties are loaded, applicarion ready event will be invoked only then. What veraions are being used.

Comment: Kotlin: 1.3.60
Spring Boot: 2.2.2

Comment: Hi, I tried with Java, Spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE, and this is working as expected. Test would invoke the applicationReadyEvent and listener is able to read property file. Please check with just printing the property value in onApplicationEvent() method

Comment: Hi, able to figure out the issue ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late response.
For some reason moving the logic to a Config class(annotated with @Configuration) and move the logic to function(annotated with @EventListener) did the trick.

Comment: Great !, thanks for sharing. On this, I checked my working Java code, listener has:   @Component
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>